# What's the difference between InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress() and InetAddress.getLocalHost().getAddress()?

Tags: network-programming, ip

Here's the code:

```
       `InetAddress me = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        System.out.println("Local host address: " + me.getHostAddress());
        System.out.println("Adress: " + Arrays.toString(me.getAddress()));`
```

And the addresses of two outputs are different, why?

Or a better question: what's the difference between those two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`getHostAddress()` and `getAddress()` returns the same information, the only difference between them is the information representation.**

`getHostAddress()` returns String, which is a human readable text. For example, in my computer, it is `"192.168.29.106"`.

`getAddress()`, on the other way, returns an array of bytes (4 bytes in the case of IPv4). For example, in my computer it is `[-64, -88, 29, 106]` -- `-64` is the signed representation of byte `0xC0 (11000000)`, which indicates `192` if it is unsigned, while `-88` represents `0xA8 (10101000)` and indicates `168` if unsigned. `29` represents byte `0x1D` and `106` represents byte `0x6A`.

`"192.168.29.106"` or `0xC0 0xA8 0x1D 0x6A`, they are the same thing.